# How to make IEnumerable<string>.Contains case-insensitive?

Tags: .net, arrays, string, linq

Suppose I have a .net Array of strings.

```
string[] strings = new string[] { "AbC", "123", "Xyz", "321" };
```

If I wanted to see if the array of strings contains "ABC", I could write

```
strings.Contains("ABC");
```

However, suppose that I want a function that will return true if the uppercase values of the strings contain "ABC".  I could uppercase the entire array, but it looks like the `.Contains` method has some overloads for specifying the comparison, but I'm confused by the syntax.

How can I use the `IEnumerable<string>.Contains()` method implement this logic?

Comment: Let me emphasize that I know that I can write `strings.select(s => s.ToUpper).Contains("ABC")`, but I'd like to know if it's possible using `.Contains` without uppercasing the array.

Comment: Nor should you change any casing because of [The turkish i Problem](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use overloaded [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) method which accepts equality comparer:

```
strings.Contains("ABC", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Also there is [strings comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) in box which you can use.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like this guy's `LambdaComparer`, which is really useful for stuff like this:

[LINQ Your Collections with IEqualityComparer and Lambda Expressions](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/linq-your-collections-with-iequalitycomparer-and-lambda-expressions.aspx)

Example Usage:

```
var comparer = new LambdaComparer<string>(
    (lhs, rhs) => lhs.Equals(rhs, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

var seq = new[]{"a","b","c","d","e"};

Debug.Assert(seq.Contains("A", comparer));
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you either prefer or are forced to use `StringComparison` and not `StringComparer`, you can add an extension method as follows:

```
public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<string> items, string value, StringComparison stringComparison)
{
    StringComparer stringComparer;

    switch (stringComparison)
    {
        case StringComparison.CurrentCulture:
            stringComparer = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
            break;
        case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
            stringComparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
            break;
        case StringComparison.InvariantCulture:
            stringComparer = StringComparer.InvariantCulture;
            break;
        case StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase:
            stringComparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
            break;
        case StringComparison.Ordinal:
            stringComparer = StringComparer.Ordinal;
            break;
        case StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase:
            stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    return items.Contains(value, stringComparer);
}
```

More variations on how to map these can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763927/elegant-way-of-converting-between-stringcomparison-and-stringcomparer).