# Check if a ListBox Item has same Text as a TextBox Text

Tags: c#

I make it short:

How can I check if a `TextBox` contains the same text as a `ListBox` item?
I try to add this function to a timer which scans it each second.
If there is a name which is in the TextBox it should show a msgbox.

Is that possible?

Comment: you can add the check in the TextBox.TextChanged Event

Comment: Yes. I Hope you can help :P

Answer (score 3):

Check this in `TextChanged` event of your `TextBox`.

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(x => x == TextBox1.Text))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Message");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
bool contains = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Contains(textToFind);
```

Note that C# is case-sensitive, if you want a case insensitive search

```
contains = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>()
     .Any(o => o.ToString().Equals(textToFind, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

if(contains)
   MessageBox.Show("ListBox contains " + textToFind);
```

Comment: @Tim: for case insensitive I'd still use contains but add the case insensitive equality comparer as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781857/how-to-make-ienumerablestring-contains-case-insensitive

Comment: I Can´t use the "textToFind" becouse i don´t look for a special name.
I Code a tool for Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3.
I added a "ban" function. + Timer which i want to check if a
Banned Player is joining the game.

I have a ListBox which all Players in the current Game.
It refreshes autoamticly. If a banned Player is in Listbox and in the TextBox ( which shows the banned Players ) it should kick him again. You know what i mean??

Comment: @user3620337: replace `textToFind` with the text you want to find, for example `TextBox123.Text`.

Comment: @Chris: `Cast<object>` returns an `IEnumerable<object>` which allows to use `Contains` but not `Contains` with a second argument `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` since an object is not a string. However, if you're sure that the `ObjectCollection` in the `ListBox` contains only strings you can use `Items.Cast<String>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ah, hadn't noticed you were casting to string. I assumed we were working with a list of strings so I see why you did it that way now.