# Elegant way of converting between StringComparison and StringComparer?

Tags: .net, string, string-comparison

Some .NET methods use [**StringComparison**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) as parameter, some use [**StringComparer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) (often in form of [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx)). The difference is clear. Is there some elegant way how to get **StringComparison** from **StringComparer** or vice versa?

I can always write simple method which uses `Case` statement, but perhaps there is already something present in .NET what I am overlooking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going from `StringComparison` to `StringComparer` is simple - just create a `Dictionary<StringComparison, StringComparer>`:

```
var map = new Dictionary<StringComparison, StringComparer>
{
    { StringComparison.Ordinal, StringComparer.Ordinal },
    // etc
};
```

There is a `StringComparer` for every `StringComparison` value, so that way works really easily. Mind you, `StringComparer.CurrentCulture` depends on the current thread culture - so if you populate the dictionary and then modify the thread's culture (or do it from a different thread with a different culture) you may end up with the wrong value. You potentially want a `Dictionary<StringComparison, Func<StringComparer>>`:

```
var map = new Dictionary<StringComparison, Func<StringComparer>>
{
    { StringComparison.Ordinal, () => StringComparer.Ordinal },
    // etc
};
```

Then you can get a comparer at any time by invoking the delegate:

```
var comparer = map[comparison]();
```

Going the other way is infeasible, because not every `StringComparer` *has* a suitable `StringComparison`. For example, suppose I (in the UK) create a `StringComparer` for French (`StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo(..., true))`. Which `StringComparison` does that represent? It's not correct for the current culture, the invariant culture, or ordinal comparisons.

Comment: Thank you for showing that "dynamic mapping" useful where culture is likely to change. Perhaps I also understand why the thing is not so simple that .NET would offer it out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't something out of the box, but you can create a simple mapping yourself between the comparsion and the comparer:

```
Dictionary<StringComparison, StringComparer> comparsionToComparer = 
                        new Dictionary<StringComparison, System.StringComparer>
{
    { StringComparison.CurrentCulture, StringComparer.CurrentCulture },
    { StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase },
    { StringComparison.InvariantCulture, StringComparer.InvariantCulture },
    { StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase },
    { StringComparison.Ordinal, StringComparer.Ordinal },
    { StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase }
}
```

And when-ever you need the proper comparer:

```
var invariantComparer = comparsionToComparer[StringComparsion.InvariantCulture];
```

**Edit:**

With C#-6 Dictionary Initializer syntax:

```
Dictionary<StringComparison, StringComparer> comparsionToComparer = 
                            new Dictionary<StringComparison, System.StringComparer>
{
    [StringComparison.CurrentCulture] = StringComparer.CurrentCulture,
    [StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase] = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,
    [StringComparison.InvariantCulture] = StringComparer.InvariantCulture,
    [StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase] = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
    [StringComparison.Ordinal] = StringComparer.Ordinal,
    [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase] = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
};
```

Also, [Jons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764112/1870803) refers to the issue of the threads current-culture, which i discarded and should probably be taken into account

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I was about to do. Before coding, I was asking whether .NET has something like this already inside.

Comment: @miroxlav There isn't an existing mapping that I know of.

Comment: Based on Jon's answer I think I perhaps understand why there isn't something like that. It might not be so simple as it appears at first sight.

Comment: @miroxlav It isn't too difficult, but something that might be tricky to get right, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

With .NET Core 2.0 or newer and .NET Standard 2.1 you can use

```
public static StringComparer FromComparison(StringComparison comparisonType);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.fromcomparison

Answer (score 1):

[vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) version based on accepted answer (and `Option Infer Off`):

```vb
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of StringComparison, Func(Of StringComparer))() _
    From {
        {StringComparison.CurrentCulture, Function() StringComparer.CurrentCulture},
        {StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, Function() StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase},
        {StringComparison.InvariantCulture, Function() StringComparer.InvariantCulture},
        {StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, Function() StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase},
        {StringComparison.Ordinal, Function() StringComparer.Ordinal},
        {StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, Function() StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase}
    }
```

Usage:

```vb
Dim comparer As StringComparer = map(comparison)()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static StringComparer ToComparer(this StringComparison comparison)
    {
        switch (comparison) {
            case StringComparison.CurrentCulture:
                return StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
            case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
                return StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
            case StringComparison.InvariantCulture:
                return StringComparer.InvariantCulture;
            case StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase:
                return StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
            case StringComparison.Ordinal:
                return StringComparer.Ordinal;
            case StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase:
                return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            default:
                break;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown StringComparison");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An a complete extension method for any one who needs quick copy+paste:

```
public static class StringComparisonExtensions
{
  // from http://stackoverflow.com/a/32764112/548304
  private static readonly Dictionary<StringComparison, Func<StringComparer>> ComparsionToComparer =
    new Dictionary<StringComparison, Func<StringComparer>>
      {
        [StringComparison.CurrentCulture] = () => StringComparer.CurrentCulture,
        [StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase] = () => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,
        [StringComparison.InvariantCulture] = () => StringComparer.InvariantCulture,
        [StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase] = () => StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
        [StringComparison.Ordinal] = () => StringComparer.Ordinal,
        [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase] = () => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
      };

  /// <summary>
  ///  Retrieves a string comparer for the given StringComparison.
  /// </summary>
  public static StringComparer ToComparer(this StringComparison comparison)
  {
    return ComparsionToComparer.GetValueOrDefault(comparison)?.Invoke();
  }
}
```