# Create an iQueryable which is case insensitive for unit testing linq to entities - NSubstitute

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, nsubstitute

I'm trying to unit test Linq to entities, I want to search for the same word in different casing and return the same word.

The current case is I'm trying to unit test searching for lower and uppercase words, EG "Hi" and "hi".

Linq to entities using entity framework currently supports this, I can search for both terms in a where clause and it does the work for me.

**Problem**:
I am trying to make a mock querable that behaves the same:

```
 public class SimpleWord
    {
        public string Text;
    }

    [Test]
    public void someTest()
    {
        //arrange
        var lowerWords = new[] { "hi" };
        var upperWords = new[] { "Hi" };

        var wordsList = new List<SimpleWord> {new SimpleWord { Text = "hi" } };
        IDbSet<SimpleWord> wordsDbSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<SimpleWord>, IDbSet<SimpleWord>>();

        //set up the mock dbSet
        var dataAsList = wordsList.ToList();
        var queryable = dataAsList.AsQueryable();
        wordsDbSet.Provider.Returns(queryable.Provider);
        wordsDbSet.Expression.Returns(queryable.Expression);
        wordsDbSet.ElementType.Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        wordsDbSet.GetEnumerator().Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());

        //act
        var resultLower = wordsDbSet.Where(wrd => lowerWords.Contains(wrd.Text)).ToList();
        var resultHigher = wordsDbSet.Where(wrd => upperWords.Contains(wrd.Text)).ToList();
        //assert
        Assert.That(resultHigher.Count, Is.EqualTo(1), "did not find upper case");
        Assert.That(resultLower.Count, Is.EqualTo(1), "did not find lower case");
    }
```

Question:
How do I make the wordsDbSet be case insensitive when i call a search on it when I do any .Where() search on it.

**I don't want to change the Acts:**

```
 var resultHigher = wordsDbSet.Where(wrd => 
                    upperWords.Contains(wrd.Text, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

**The answer I'm looking for is a change to the arrange:**

```
wordsDbSet.When(contains.IsCalled).Return(contains.OrdinalIgnoreCasing)
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I don't think you can (in an easy way). You'll have to rewrite the full `EnumerableQuery` (that is the class that implements `AsQueryable()`) class to inject the code you want. Note that you can take its source from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq) but it is still a big work.

Comment: The other way (changing the default comparison) is impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138387/globally-set-string-compare-compareinfo-compare-to-ordinal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok... Doable but quite long (not very complex... Only very long). The main problem is that implementing `IQueryable<>` and `IQueryProvider` is a pain, with little explanation about how it works (you can copy some code that you can find in the internet, but there is little explanation about why and how it works).

What I've written is a `IQueryable<>` wrapper that "wraps" a `IQueryable<>` object (like the one returned by `AsQueryable()` and "on the fly" replaces in all the expression trees passed some `string` methods (plus the `Enumerable.Contains<string>`) with corresponding overloads that accept a `StringComparison`/`StringComparer`. Use it like:

```
var arr = new[] { "foo " };
var query = new[] { "Foo", "Bar", "bar" }
    .AsQueryable()
    .AsStringComparison(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

// query is a IQueryable<>

var res = query
    .Where(x => string.Compare(x, "foo") < 0)
    .Where(x => x.CompareTo("foo") < 0)
    .Where(x => string.Compare(x, 0, "foo", 0, 3) < 0)
    .Where(x => x.Contains("foo"))
    .Where(x => string.Equals(x, "foo"))
    .Where(x => x.Equals("foo"))
    .Where(x => arr.Contains(x))
    .Where(x => x == "foo")
    .Where(x => x != "foo")
;
```

(that is the list of all the methods that I'm replacing)

and the implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public static class StringComparisonQueryableWrapper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> AsStringComparison<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        return new StringComparisonQueryableWrapper<T>(query, comparisonType);
    }
}

public class StringComparisonQueryableWrapper<T> : IQueryable<T>, IQueryable, IQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryable<T> baseQuery;
    public readonly StringComparison ComparisonType;

    public StringComparisonQueryableWrapper(IQueryable<T> baseQuery, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        this.baseQuery = baseQuery;
        this.ComparisonType = comparisonType;
    }

    Expression IQueryable.Expression => baseQuery.Expression;

    Type IQueryable.ElementType => baseQuery.ElementType;

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => this;

    IQueryable IQueryProvider.CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        Type type = expression.Type;
        var iqueryableT = type.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>)).Single();
        Type type2 = iqueryableT.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var thisType = typeof(StringComparisonQueryableWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
        var createQueryMethod = thisType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Where(x => x.Name == "System.Linq.IQueryProvider.CreateQuery" && x.IsGenericMethod).Single().MakeGenericMethod(type2);
        var queryable = (IQueryable)createQueryMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { expression });
        return queryable;
    }

    IQueryable<TElement> IQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        var expression2 = TransformExpression(expression);
        var query = baseQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression2);
        return new StringComparisonQueryableWrapper<TElement>(query, ComparisonType);
    }

    object IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        var expression2 = TransformExpression(expression);
        return baseQuery.Provider.Execute(expression2);
    }

    TResult IQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        var expression2 = TransformExpression(expression);
        return baseQuery.Provider.Execute<TResult>(expression2);
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return baseQuery.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return baseQuery.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private Expression TransformExpression(Expression expression)
    {
        Expression expression2 = new StringComparisonExpressionTranformer(ComparisonType).Visit(expression);
        return expression2;
    }

    private class StringComparisonExpressionTranformer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly StringComparison comparisonType;

        private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<MethodInfo, Func<MethodCallExpression, StringComparison, Expression>> transformers;
        private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<MethodInfo, Func<BinaryExpression, StringComparison, Expression>> transformers2;

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764110/613130
        private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<StringComparison, StringComparer> comparisonToComparer = new Dictionary<StringComparison, System.StringComparer>
        {
            { StringComparison.CurrentCulture, StringComparer.CurrentCulture },
            { StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase },
            { StringComparison.InvariantCulture, StringComparer.InvariantCulture },
            { StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase },
            { StringComparison.Ordinal, StringComparer.Ordinal },
            { StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase }
        };

        static StringComparisonExpressionTranformer()
        {
            var transformers = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, Func<MethodCallExpression, StringComparison, Expression>>();

            {
                // string.Compare("foo", "bar")
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Compare), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers.Add(method, Compare);
            }

            {
                // string.Compare("foo", 0, "bar", 0, 3)
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Compare), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(int) }, null);
                transformers.Add(method, CompareIndexLength);
            }

            {
                // "foo".CompareTo("bar")
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.CompareTo), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers.Add(method, CompareTo);
            }

            {
                // "foo".Contains("bar")
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers.Add(method, Contains);
            }

            {
                // string.Equals("foo", "bar")
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Equals), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers.Add(method, EqualsStatic);
            }

            {
                // "foo".Equals("bar")
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Equals), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers.Add(method, EqualsInstance);
            }

            {
                // Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(source, "foo")
                var method = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                              where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains)
                              let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                              where args.Length == 1
                              let pars = x.GetParameters()
                              where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                  pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                  pars[1].ParameterType == args[0]
                              select x).Single();

                // Enumerable.Contains<string>(source, "foo")
                var method2 = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

                transformers.Add(method2, EnumerableContains);
            }

            // TODO: all the various Array.Find*, Array.IndexOf

            StringComparisonExpressionTranformer.transformers = transformers;

            var transformers2 = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, Func<BinaryExpression, StringComparison, Expression>>();

            {
                // ==
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("op_Equality", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers2.Add(method, OpEquality);
            }

            {
                // !=
                var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("op_Inequality", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
                transformers2.Add(method, OpInequality);
            }

            StringComparisonExpressionTranformer.transformers2 = transformers2;
        }

        public StringComparisonExpressionTranformer(StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            this.comparisonType = comparisonType;
        }

        // methods
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            Func<MethodCallExpression, StringComparison, Expression> transformer;

            if (transformers.TryGetValue(node.Method, out transformer))
            {
                Expression node2 = transformer(node, comparisonType);
                return Visit(node2);
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

        // operators
        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            Func<BinaryExpression, StringComparison, Expression> transformer;

            if (node.Method != null && transformers2.TryGetValue(node.Method, out transformer))
            {
                Expression node2 = transformer(node, comparisonType);
                return Visit(node2);
            }

            return base.VisitBinary(node);
        }

        private static readonly MethodInfo StringEqualsStatic = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Equals), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) }, null);
        private static readonly MethodInfo StringEqualsInstance = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Equals), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) }, null);

        private static readonly MethodInfo StringCompareStatic = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Compare), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) }, null);
        private static readonly MethodInfo StringCompareIndexLengthStatic = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Compare), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(StringComparison) }, null);

        private static readonly MethodInfo StringIndexOfInstance = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.IndexOf), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) }, null);

        private static readonly MethodInfo EnumerableContainsStatic = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                                       where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains)
                                                                       let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                                                       where args.Length == 1
                                                                       let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                                                       where pars.Length == 3 &&
                                                                           pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                                                           pars[1].ParameterType == args[0] &&
                                                                           pars[2].ParameterType == typeof(IEqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(args[0])
                                                                       select x).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

        private static Expression Compare(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Call(StringCompareStatic, exp.Arguments[0], exp.Arguments[1], Expression.Constant(comparisonType));
        }

        private static Expression CompareIndexLength(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Call(StringCompareIndexLengthStatic, exp.Arguments[0], exp.Arguments[1], exp.Arguments[2], exp.Arguments[3], exp.Arguments[4], Expression.Constant(comparisonType));
        }

        private static Expression CompareTo(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Call(StringCompareStatic, exp.Object, exp.Arguments[0], Expression.Constant(comparisonType));
        }

        private static Expression Contains(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            // No "".Contains(, StringComparison). Translate to "".IndexOf(, StringComparison) != -1
            return Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Call(exp.Object, StringIndexOfInstance, exp.Arguments[0], Expression.Constant(comparisonType)), Expression.Constant(-1));
        }

        private static Expression EqualsStatic(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Call(StringEqualsStatic, exp.Arguments[0], exp.Arguments[1], Expression.Constant(comparisonType));
        }

        private static Expression EqualsInstance(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Call(exp.Object, StringEqualsInstance, exp.Arguments[0], Expression.Constant(comparisonType));
        }

        private static Expression EnumerableContains(MethodCallExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            StringComparer comparer = comparisonToComparer[comparisonType];
            return Expression.Call(EnumerableContainsStatic, exp.Arguments[0], exp.Arguments[1], Expression.Constant(comparer));
        }


        private static Expression OpEquality(BinaryExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Call(StringEqualsStatic, exp.Left, exp.Right, Expression.Constant(comparisonType));
        }

        private static Expression OpInequality(BinaryExpression exp, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            return Expression.Not(Expression.Call(StringEqualsStatic, exp.Left, exp.Right, Expression.Constant(comparisonType)));
        }
    }
}
```

If you take a look, there is a very simple proxy `IQueryable`/`IQueryProvider` implementation (`StringComparisonQueryableWrapper<T>`) that uses an `ExpressionVisitor` (`StringComparisonExpressionTranformer`) to find and replace some particular `MethodCallExpression` (calls to methods) and `BinaryExpression` (the `==` and `!=` operators) with `MethodCallExpression` that use methods with the `StringComparison`/`StringComparer`. Missing are replacers for `Array.IndexOf`, `Enumerable.SequenceEquals`...

Comment: wow, thanks for your hard work on this, it solved the issue i was having