# Trying to Mock IQueryable Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to test that a query is not case sensitive. This production code works:

```
public ILookup<string, EEntry> GetEEntries(int batchId, List<string> employeeIds)
{
  using (WithNoLock())
  {
    var result = from e in _entities.EEntries
                 where e.CPayBatchProcessId == batchId
                       && (!e.Blocked.HasValue || e.Blocked.Value != true)
                       && employeeIds.Contains(e.Id)
                 select e;

    return result.ToLookup(e => e.Id, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

I can't get the unit test to work. My first attempt failed because I believe the list was `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. However, my attempt at `IQueryable` is not passing. The query is case sensitive, and I don't want it to be. This is what I did to make it `IQueryable`:

```
[TestCase("abc", "ABC")]
public void EEntriesAreCaseInsensitive(string employeeId1Input, string employeeId1Output)
{
  var payEntries = new List<EEntry>
  {
    new EEntry() {CPayBatchProcessId = 8, Id = employeeId1Input},
    new EEntry() {CPayBatchProcessId = 8, Id = "123"}
  }.AsQueryable();

  var payEntriesDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<EEntry>>();
  payEntriesDbSet.As<IQueryable<EEntry>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(payEntries.Provider);
  payEntriesDbSet.As<IQueryable<EEntry>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(payEntries.Expression);
  payEntriesDbSet.As<IQueryable<EEntry>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(payEntries.ElementType);
  payEntriesDbSet.As<IQueryable<EEntry>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(payEntries.GetEnumerator);

  var context = new Mock<ISomeContext>();
  context.Setup(x => x.EEntries).Returns(payEntriesDbSet.Object);

  var employeeIds = new List<string>() { "aBc", "dEf", "gHi" };

  var repo = new EEntriesRepository(context.Object);
  var payEntryRecords = repo.GetEEntries(8, employeeIds);

  Assert.IsTrue(payEntryRecords.Contains(employeeId1Output));
}
```

What am I missing?

Note: The getter for EEntry.Id returns `.ToUpper()`. The production code correctly ignores that. The test code does not.

Comment: Wont `.Contains()` use the `List` implementation regardless? Which return false. Changing it to match your production code: `employeeIds.Contains(employeeId1Output, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` returns true.

Comment: When running for real, against the DB, the query syntax gets converted to this: `([Extent1].[id] IN ('aBc', 'dEf', 'gHi'))`. That gets run against the DB, which is case-insensitive.

Comment: What I'm missing may be that the query syntax doesn't get converted to SQL just because it's IQueryable. During the unit test, it's all in memory. Maybe I'm expecting something that's not possible.

Comment: What happens if you go back to IEnumerable and do `var payEntryRecords = repo.GetEEntries(8, employeeIds).ToList();`? Does the `.Contains` overload that ignores case work then?

Comment: I think it just hit me. I'm trying to test the case sensitivity in the query, but that's not really what I should be testing. That's like testing SQL Server functionality in a unit test. What I need to do, in the unit test, is make sure the query returns data (taking case sensitivity into account), and then test that the `ILookup` returns values while ignoring the case.

Comment: To answer your question, it wouldn't matter if `.Contains()` worked in that case, because it causes a run-time error when trying to convert to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're using `employeeId1Output` anywhere but you're asserting that it should be in the `payEntryRecords`. Based on your code, it looks like you should be asserting whether `employeeId1Input` is in `payEntryRecords` instead. You're explicitly adding `employeeId1Input` to your `payEntries` object.

Comment: `employeeId1Output` is purposefully a different casing of the input. I want to assert that the ID is there, regardless of its case. If I were to change the first employeeId to "ABC" (instead of "aBc"), the test would pass.

Comment: Ah ok it's an issue with the `.contains` method, not your query. @mxmissile is correct about the overload. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781857/how-to-make-ienumerablestring-contains-case-insensitive) question  might help too

Comment: I actually tried what that link is suggesting, but SQL Server doesn't recognize that and fails on it.

Answer (score 0):

The case insensitive nature of string comparisons depends on your database provider. SQL Server will compare strings case insensitive, while something like PostgreSQL, I believe, does not.

So if your code logic does `employeeIds.Contains(e.Id)`, EF will pass the equivalent logic to the DB. When substituting that with a Mock and `List<T>.AsQueryable()`, C# will treat strings as case sensitive, where SQL Server doesn't care. IN() clauses and string comparisons are case insensitive.

I'd consider using the below, or something similar to ensure that the string comparison is performed case insensitive. This should work across DB providers and place nicer with mocked data.

```
public ILookup<string, EEntry> GetEEntries(int batchId, List<string> employeeIds)
{
  if(employeeIds == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("employeeIds");

  employeeIds = employeeIds.ConvertAll(x => x.ToUpper());
  using (WithNoLock())
  {
    var result = from e in _entities.EEntries
                 where e.CPayBatchProcessId == batchId
                       && (!e.Blocked.HasValue || e.Blocked.Value != true)
                       && employeeIds.Contains(e.Id.ToUpper())
                 select e;

    return result.ToLookup(e => e.Id, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like that except for one thing: The original code worked correctly with SQL Server. It just didn't work with the unit test. Ideally, I shouldn't have to change production code just to get a unit test to work. I think the real answer is to only test the `ILookup` return object, and that's what I ended up doing.