# Input must be equal to one of 5 different string values

Tags: c#

User input must be equal to one of 5 different strings, if not the user must input again, until the input is equal to one of the 5 strings.

I wrote some code, it works the way it should if the first entered input is equal to one of the 5 strings, if it is not, the program is stuck in an endless loop.

```
novaDrzava.PrevladujocaVera = Console.ReadLine();

var vera = novaDrzava.PrevladujocaVera;
var prvacrkaVera = vera.Substring(0, 1);
var ostaloVera = vera.Substring(1, vera.Length - 1);

prvacrkaVera = prvacrkaVera.ToUpper();
ostaloVera = ostaloVera.ToLower();

vera = prvacrkaVera + ostaloVera;


while (true)
{
    if(vera == "Krščanstvo")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Krscanstvo")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Hinduizem")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Islam")
    {
        break;
    }
    if (vera == "Budizem")
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Vnesite ustrezno vero");


    vera = Console.ReadLine();
    vera = prvacrkaVera + ostaloVera;
}
```

Comment: Well, your `Console.ReadLine` is outside of the loop so naturally it won't change - that causes the infinite loop.

Comment: looks like its inside the loop to me. You may need to scroll down, there's a second one.

Comment: @Quibblesome Yes, but get's overwritten immediately to the previous value

Comment: after `vera = Console.Readline()`, add these 4 lines: `var prvacrkaVera = vera.Substring(0, 1);
var ostaloVera = vera.Substring(1, vera.Length - 1);

prvacrkaVera = prvacrkaVera.ToUpper();
ostaloVera = ostaloVera.ToLower();`

Comment: **[How to use the free Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Instead of your repetitive `if` statements, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781857/how-to-make-ienumerablestring-contains-case-insensitive and create a collection of strings that contains your acceptable values and then use `IEnumerable<string>.Contains` to decide if they are good.

Comment: @Flydog57 Like my answer? :)

Comment: Just move all the lines that prepare the upper/lower string inside the while block and remove the last two lines. Move also the Console.WriteLine as the first statement inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to re-assign the values of `prvacrkaVera` and `ostaloVera` in the loop

```
while (true)
{
    if(vera == "Krščanstvo")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Krscanstvo")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Hinduizem")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Islam")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (vera == "Budizem")
    {
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Vnesite ustrezno vero");
    vera = Console.ReadLine();

    prvacrkaVera = vera.Substring(0, 1);
    ostaloVera = vera.Substring(1, vera.Length - 1);

    prvacrkaVera = prvacrkaVera.ToUpper();
    ostaloVera = ostaloVera.ToLower();

    vera = prvacrkaVera + ostaloVera;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't fully read your code since the identifiers aren't in English. But, given the rest of your question, I think this might be what you want:

```
var words = new List<string>
{
    "Krščanstvo",
    "Krscanstvo",
    "Hinduizem",
    "Islam",
    "Budizem"
};

while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (words.Contains(input, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        break;

    Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please try again");
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: please provide a reason so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Not my downvote but I can understand that you haven't solved the main problem in the question. Why we have an infinite loop?

Comment: @Steve Huh? It isn't infinite...It breaks out of the loop when one of the choices is typed in. Check out the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3o3DE) to see it working as OP asked for.

Comment: Bad choice of words. I mean you haven't explained to error in the OP code

Comment: @Steve I can barely read his code since it isn't in English, as I mentioned in my answer. But I did answer his question as asked "`User input must be equal to one of 5 different strings, if not the user must input again, until the input is equal to one of the 5 strings.`" My answer does exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

Use a switch statement so you can easily detect when other values are entered

```
           while (true)
            {
                switch(vera)
                {
                    case "Krscanstvo" : 
                    break;

                    case "Krščanstvo" : 
                    break;

                    case "Hinduizem" : 
                    break;

                    case "Islam" : 
                    break;

                    case "Budizem" : 
                    break;

                    default :
                        break; //exit while loop
                    break;
                }
            }
```